# DRF - making api available only to known clients

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a DRF api which does not have any authentication system (because the concept of a `user` is meaningless there). And yet I want to make the api be restricted only to known clients. In other words, I want to come up with an `api-to-api` authentication rather than `user-to-api` authentication. Is that possible in DRF ? And are there any ready-to-use libs out there ?

Comment: Yes you can create a custom authentication class that works with api keys for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a permission class for it. Define a permission class that inherited from `permissions.BasePermission`

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class SamplePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.META.get('HTTP_YOUR_KEY','') in ['some_key']
```

and define it inside your view as permission_classes

```
class SampleViewSet(views.APIView):
    ...
    permission_classes = [SamplePermission]
```

I can't say this is the best way but you can use it with this.